# How to determine all the possible 3 layer combinations out of many files

Tags: python, arrays, list, image

I have a list of 21 grayscale images. I want to determine and save all the possible 3 layer combinations out of these 21 images. Can anyone a suggest a way in python?

Comment: Take a look at `itertools.permutations()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 21 grayscale images, you could read them all and you would get 21 indices from 0 20.

The code to choose the indices combinations could look like:

```
import itertools

listOfIndices = list(range(20))
combinations = list(set(list(itertools.combinations(listOfIndices,3))))
```

This works for any combination without repetitions. If you are ok with the repetitions, the last line becomes:

```
combinations = list(itertools.combinations(listOfIndices,3))
```

where each of the element is a 3-index tuple.

Comment: I think it's overkill to import `numpy` just to use the `arange()` function, considering we're using integer and therefore the build-tin `range()` function is equivalent.

Comment: I agree.  i will modify the answer!